New Construction Electrical from meter box to: 1-200 amp house service and 1 -separate RV Pedestal with 120 receptacle, and 30 and 50 amp receptacles
We live in Nevada and have 200 amp service. We are running from the meter box to the house (150 ft) with 4/0 4/0 2/0 AL URD to the service panel. We also want to run from the meter to a campground RV pedestal (130 ft) housing a 120v, a 30amp, and a 50 amp receptacle. The plan is to use #2 thhn AL URD in a triplex configuration from a 60 amp breaker at the meter.
Question: Do we need to ground at the RV pedestal or do we run a ground wire from the meter box through the conduit into the pedestal?

I suspect that you can run 3-wire to the house, but NOT if the house is not the only thing being fed from the meter - so by adding the RV pedestal from the meter, you'll need to ground the meter (that will be your main) and run grounds from there to both the house and the RV pedestal as sub-panels. Each will also need local grounding electrodes. If you supply the pedestal from the house, that complication only exists for the house-to-pedestal run.

30 and 50 refer to Amps. 110 ??? I suspect you mean "110V 'ordinary' receptacle" in which case really it is 120V 20A, and the 30A is also generally (don't ask me why) also 120V. So: 120V 20A, 120V 30A, 240V 50A. If that is correct, please update the question. If not, please clarify.

Why is the 30A 120V? becuase that's what a "30A RV Connection" on a TT-30 plug is. RVs only do 240V when it's a 50A plug.

Is your meter box just a meter, or a meter/main?  Also, who do you have for an electric utility?

Thank you for the responses.

It is a grounded meter/main installed by the rural utility. The 200 amp panel at the house will also be grounded. We are running separate lines so it sounds like we will need a ground wire to the house and the RV pedestal along with the grounding rods. The RV pedestal is going to be connected first while we are building the house which is the reason we are not running from the house to the pedestal.

@dawnscott -- what make and model is that meter main?

@ThreePhaseEel It is a Milbank, not sure of the model.. Meter on top and circuit breakers beneath.

@dawnscott -- is there not a label on the inside of the door to the breaker section?
